# errors building a condas environment from scratch

Tags: linux, conda

I am trying to follow this tutorial [this tutorial](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tutorials/build-pkgs.html) so that I can learn how to build a `condas` package from scratch. As per the instructions, I have created a new directory `pyinstrument` and in that directory I have added the meta.yaml, bld.bat and bld.sh files listed on the site.

Specifically I downloaded the meta.yaml file with

```
wget https://conda.io/docs/_downloads/meta1.yaml
mv meta1.yaml meta.yaml
```

and, using emacs I copied

```
"%PYTHON%" setup.py install --single-version-externally-managed --record=record.txt
if errorlevel 1 exit 1
```

into a new file called `bld.bat`

and I copied

```
$PYTHON setup.py install --single-version-externally-managed --record=record.txt  # Python command to install the script.
```

into another file called `build.sh`

I then moved outside of the directory with `cd ..`
and tried to build it with

```
conda-build pyinstrument
```

I then get the following mess of output, with several warning and error messages, which appears to be a failed installation.

> ```
> ohnoplus@mymachine:~/Practice$ conda-build pyinstrument
> Adding in variants from internal_defaults
> INFO:conda_build.variants:Adding in variants from internal_defaults
> Attempting to finalize metadata for pyinstrument
> INFO:conda_build.metadata:Attempting to finalize metadata for pyinstrument
> Solving environment: ...working... done
> Solving environment: ...working... done
> BUILD START: ['pyinstrument-0.13.1-py36_0.tar.bz2']
> Solving environment: ...working... done
> Solving environment: ...working... done
>
> ## Package Plan ##
>
>   environment location: /home/ohnoplus/anaconda3/conda-bld/pyinstrument_1522708563689/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold
>
>
> The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:
>
>     ca-certificates: 2018.03.07-0     
>     certifi:         2018.1.18-py36_0 
>     libedit:         3.1-heed3624_0   
>     libffi:          3.2.1-hd88cf55_4 
>     libgcc-ng:       7.2.0-hdf63c60_3 
>     libstdcxx-ng:    7.2.0-hdf63c60_3 
>     ncurses:         6.0-h9df7e31_2   
>     openssl:         1.0.2o-h20670df_0
>     pip:             9.0.3-py36_0     
>     python:          3.6.5-hc3d631a_0 
>     readline:        7.0-ha6073c6_4   
>     setuptools:      39.0.1-py36_0    
>     sqlite:          3.22.0-h1bed415_0
>     tk:              8.6.7-hc745277_3 
>     wheel:           0.31.0-py36_0    
>     xz:              5.2.3-h55aa19d_2 
>     zlib:            1.2.11-ha838bed_2
>
> Preparing transaction: ...working... done
> Verifying transaction: ...working... done
> Executing transaction: ...working... done
> Cloning into bare repository '/home/ohnoplus/anaconda3/conda-bld/git_cache/github.com/joerick/pyinstrument.git'...
> remote: Counting objects: 743, done.
> remote: Compressing objects: 100% (7/7), done.
> remote: Total 743 (delta 0), reused 2 (delta 0), pack-reused 736
> Receiving objects: 100% (743/743), 779.75 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
> Resolving deltas: 100% (431/431), done.
> Checking connectivity... done.
> Cloning into '/home/ohnoplus/anaconda3/conda-bld/pyinstrument_1522708563689/work'...
> done.
> checkout: 'v0.13.1'
> Note: checking out 'v0.13.1'.
>
> You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
> changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
> state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.
>
> If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
> do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:
>
>   git checkout -b <new-branch-name>
>
> HEAD is now at 94b89f9... Bump version
> ==> git log -n1 <==
>
> commit 94b89f9a13a44a5a4b244c9aac9a7b81a4359ce5
> Author: Joe Rickerby <joerick@mac.com>
> Date:   Wed Aug 20 21:40:50 2014 +0100
>
>     Bump version
>
> ==> git describe --tags --dirty <==
>
> v0.13.1
>
> ==> git status <==
>
> HEAD detached at v0.13.1
> nothing to commit, working directory clean
>
> source tree in: /home/ohnoplus/anaconda3/conda-bld/pyinstrument_1522708563689/work
> Packaging pyinstrument
> INFO:conda_build.build:Packaging pyinstrument
> Packaging pyinstrument-0.13.1-py36_0
> INFO:conda_build.build:Packaging pyinstrument-0.13.1-py36_0
> No files or script found for output pyinstrument
> WARNING:conda_build.build:No files or script found for output pyinstrument
> number of files: 0
> Fixing permissions
> updating: pyinstrument-0.13.1-py36_0.tar.bz2
> TEST START: /home/ohnoplus/anaconda3/conda-bld/linux-64/pyinstrument-0.13.1-py36_0.tar.bz2
> Updating index at /home/ohnoplus/anaconda3/conda-bld/linux-64 to make package installable with dependencies
> INFO:conda_build.build:Updating index at /home/ohnoplus/anaconda3/conda-bld/linux-64 to make package installable
> with dependencies
> Updating index at /home/ohnoplus/anaconda3/conda-bld/noarch to make package installable with dependencies
> INFO:conda_build.build:Updating index at /home/ohnoplus/anaconda3/conda-bld/noarch to make package installable
> with dependencies
> Adding in variants from /tmp/tmpzr3fnfza/info/recipe/conda_build_config.yaml
> INFO:conda_build.variants:Adding in variants from /tmp/tmpzr3fnfza/info/recipe/conda_build_config.yaml
> Renaming work directory,  /home/ohnoplus/anaconda3/conda-bld/pyinstrument_1522708563689/work to 
> /home/ohnoplus/anaconda3/conda-bld/pyinstrument_1522708563689/work_moved_pyinstrument-0.13.1-py36_0_linux-64
> Solving environment: ...working... done
>
> ## Package Plan ##
>
>   environment location: /home/ohnoplus/anaconda3/conda-bld/pyinstrument_1522708563689/_test_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placeh
>
>
> The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:
>
>     ca-certificates: 2018.03.07-0           
>     certifi:         2018.1.18-py36_0       
>     libedit:         3.1-heed3624_0         
>     libffi:          3.2.1-hd88cf55_4       
>     libgcc-ng:       7.2.0-hdf63c60_3       
>     libstdcxx-ng:    7.2.0-hdf63c60_3       
>     ncurses:         6.0-h9df7e31_2         
>     openssl:         1.0.2o-h20670df_0      
>     pip:             9.0.3-py36_0           
>     pyinstrument:    0.13.1-py36_0     local
>     python:          3.6.5-hc3d631a_0       
>     readline:        7.0-ha6073c6_4         
>     setuptools:      39.0.1-py36_0          
>     sqlite:          3.22.0-h1bed415_0      
>     tk:              8.6.7-hc745277_3       
>     wheel:           0.31.0-py36_0          
>     xz:              5.2.3-h55aa19d_2       
>     zlib:            1.2.11-ha838bed_2      
>
> Preparing transaction: ...working... done
> Verifying transaction: ...working... done
> Executing transaction: ...working... done
> import: 'pyinstrument'
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/home/ohnoplus/anaconda3/conda-bld/pyinstrument_1522708563689/test_tmp/run_test.py",
> line 2, in <module>
>     import pyinstrument
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyinstrument'
> Tests failed for pyinstrument-0.13.1-py36_0.tar.bz2 - moving package to /home/ohnoplus/anaconda3/conda-bld/broken
> WARNING:conda_build.build:Tests failed for pyinstrument-0.13.1-py36_0.tar.bz2 - moving package to
> /home/ohnoplus/anaconda3/conda-bld/broken
> removing: pyinstrument-0.13.1-py36_0.tar.bz2
> TESTS FAILED: pyinstrument-0.13.1-py36_0.tar.bz2
> ```

I'm not even sure where to start debugging this, and any help is appreciated. Here's some information about my system: I'm happy to provide more as needed, or even run this on a brand new virtualbox so that this can be fully replicated.

```
uname -a
```

> ```
> Linux mymachine 4.13.0-37-generic #42~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Mar 7
> 16:03:28 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
> ```

```
conda info
```

> ```
>    active environment : None
>        user config file : /home/ohnoplus/.condarc
>  populated config files : 
>           conda version : 4.5.0
>     conda-build version : 3.8.0
>          python version : 3.6.1.final.0
>        base environment : /home/ohnoplus/anaconda3  (writable)
>            channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
>                           https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
>                           https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/linux-64
>                           https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/noarch
>                           https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
>                           https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
>                           https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/linux-64
>                           https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/noarch
>           package cache : /home/ohnoplus/anaconda3/pkgs
>                           /home/ohnoplus/.conda/pkgs
>        envs directories : /home/ohnoplus/anaconda3/envs
>                           /home/ohnoplus/.conda/envs
>                platform : linux-64
>              user-agent : conda/4.5.0 requests/2.14.2 CPython/3.6.1 Linux/4.13.0-37-generic ubuntu/16.04 glibc/2.23
>                 UID:GID : 1000:1000
>              netrc file : None
>            offline mode : False
> ```

Comment: I would suggest doing `conda skeleton pypi pyinstrument` in a different directory and comparing the meta.yaml and build.sh files

Comment: Good idea. Indeed, there are a number of key differences there.